# How can I get the uploaded file details from uploadify after completion

Tags: php, uploadify

How should I retrieve the uploaded file details from uploadify after the completion of the upload process.

I want to do a process in the uploaded file. 
But when I use the uploadify it simply uploads the file to a location through the uploadify.php which I customized. 
I want this uploadify process to redirect to a page after completed with the details of the file such as filename and the targeted location where I will proceed with my second operation on the file uploaded

**Updates**

This is what my code as of now

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 0.8em/1.6em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
fieldset {
    width: 500px;
}

#sample {
    display:table;
}
#sampleFile {
    float: left;
    display:table-cell;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
#download {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: table;
}
.dlImage {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.dlText {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}
.fileDetails {
    color: red;
}
.releaseDate{
    margin-top: -3px;
    color: gray;
}
</style>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Uploadify scriptData Sample</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
        'folder': 'files',
        'multi': false,
        'displayData': 'speed',
        'onComplete'  : function(event, queueID, fileObj, reponse, data) {    
            location.href="complete.php"; 
        }
    });


});

</script>
</head>

<body>






<div id="sample">
<div id="sampleFile">

 <fieldset style="border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; padding: 8px; padding-bottom:0px; margin: 8px 0">
        <legend><strong>Sélectionner l'image à imprimer :</strong></legend>


        <div id="fileUpload">You have a problem with your javascript</div>
        <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload').fileUploadStart()">Start Upload</a>        <p></p>
 </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

on the second page I do want to echo the file name that is uploaded 
I have there in the second page complete.php

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);

echo $_FILES['type'];
echo $_FILES['tmp_name'];
echo $_FILES['name'];
echo $_FILES['size'];

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know that you can get the `filename`, `filpath` inside the `onComplete` event like this:-

```
onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, reponse, data) 
{
    alert fileObj.name; //The name of the uploaded file
    alert fileObj.filePath; //The path on the server to the uploaded file

    location.href= "complete.php?filename="+fileObj.name+"&filepath="+fileObj.filePath; //Here you can do a javascript redirect
}
```

Check the documentation for further details http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/

Are you looking for those values? If not let me know

**Updates**

As per your question updates, you have 2 options.

Either to do the "some process" after the file upload in the uploadify.php. You can see the file `uploadify.php` which comes with the uploadify plugin.  There you have the `$_FILES['Filedata']` array containing all the file info. You may do the post processing here itself (by calling a function  better instead of writing lots of code in uploadify's core code)

*in uploadify.php*
    $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] //file name

Or like I said, get the file name and path inside the `onComplete` event. Then pass these params like this :-

```
 location.href= "complete.php?filename="+fileObj.name+"&filepath="+fileObj.filePath;
```

I think this is better. You may send an ajax request instead to do the entire process (file upload + your "some process") without loading the page again.
  Write a [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) request inside the `onComplete` event with those parameters and post to "complete.php"

**Getting parameters inside `onComplete` which are not available by default**

You have to use the `response` parameter available inside `onComplete`
I worked on uploadify version 2.1.0 so my solution will work for sure on that version.
If you want only one parameter, you can echo that at the end of `uploadify.php`
I did the following thing:-

In my `uploadify.php` changed (this was in the original uploadify.php):-

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
echo "1";
```

to this:-

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
echo $tempFile;
```

and then inside the `onComplete` event did an explode -

```
var tmpName = reponse;
```

If however, you want to get more than one parameter inside `onComplete`, this is a trick I can give (this is not a good approach, but I was not able to return multiple params by any other way - I tried returning json array etc.):-

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
echo $param1.'%%__%%'.$param2;
```

and then inside the `onComplete` event did an explode -

```
var paramsArray = explode('%%__%%',reponse);
param1 = paramsArray[0]; 
param2 = paramsArray[1];
```

Comment: I want to get the uploaded files name on my second page. I added some more content to my question please check it. Likewise what I did as of now and need the uploaded file name to do some process in my second page

Comment: I have updated my answer. Are you not getting the file name and path inside the `onComplete` event ?

Comment: can you please update how the post process works here in the oncomplete event if I want the filename & filepath to send by post method to complete.php

Comment: yes now I got the filename & filepath.. but is i get the posted values from the uploaded file then I can do all the process here in the complete.php instead of doing it in upload.php by calling $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] in complete.php right??

Comment: check my updates, for uploadify versions higher than 2.1.0, you may need to do some adjustments

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the details of the uploaded file by echoing below line;

```
print_r($_FIELS);
```

OR you can `echo` all the fields of uploded files.

```
echo $_FIELS['type'];
echo $_FIELS['tmp_name'];
echo $_FIELS['name'];
echo $_FIELS['size'];
```

i m right if i understood you what you want to saying. but please do comment if you searching for anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean to say that I want to echo these variables in the second page where I get redirected

Comment: no, actually i just informing you that by this way you can get all the variables of uploaded files. echo is just a way by which you can see your values if it is wrong or wright.

Comment: otherwise you can get all the variable by using without ECHO.

Comment: you can use this in your page where it does redirect after uploading file. i.e : if you want to get file type then you can write like this $filetype = $_FILES['filename']['type']; etc...

Comment: `$_FIELS` should be `$_FILES`

Comment: sorry I am not getting anything in the second page 
i used : - 'onComplete'  : function(event, queueID, fileObj, reponse, data) {    
   location.href="complete.php"; 
  } 
---------------------------------------------------
and put your code print_r($_FILES);

echo $_FILES['type'];
echo $_FILES['tmp_name'];
echo $_FILES['name'];
echo $_FILES['size']; in complete.php