# how to get file name in uploadify

Tags: jquery, uploadify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the uploaded file details from uploadify after completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386554/how-can-i-get-the-uploaded-file-details-from-uploadify-after-completion)

hi,
how to get the uploaded file name and it's extension by jquery in with uploadify tool?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386554/how-can-i-get-the-uploaded-file-details-from-uploadify-after-completion

Answer (score 0):

Take a peak at the uploadify.php file.  This has a basic process for getting the information from the uploaded file for processing. i.e line 30.